# A sentence problem about the conjunction "still"

Tags: word-choice

> Some place great emphasis on mechanical guarding. Others stress safe work practices by observing rules or regulations. _____ others depend on an emotional appeal to the worker. But, there are certain basic ideas that must be used in every program if maximum results are to be obtained.

the options for the blank is 
*A. Some; B. Many; C. Even; D.Still*

the correct answer is D.still.

Can you guys explain why choose "still" instead of "some" ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've one "**others**" already,the other others are "**still other others**". Catch the point?

Comment: @SovereignSun sorry, i didn't quite catch that.  i kind of understand that "still" is right here, but could you tell me why "some" is wrong ?

Comment: "**Some others**" is possible, but that will leave us with the rest who are "**still others**".

Comment: How about [*still*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/still): "10.  even; yet  
used as an intensifier with a comparative form, etc.  
*cold yesterday, but **still** colder today*"

Answer (score 1):

"Still" here is not a conjunction but an adjective modifying "others."  It's demonstrating that there is yet a third set of people who focus on yet another thing.  (You can substitute "still" for "yet" in my sentence.)

You didn't ask, but there should be no comma after the "But."  ;-)